# Vue 3 component does not update on second creation

Tags: vue.js

I have a custom Vue component `ProgressBar` which shows a progress bar. It is being updated through the parent component by calling the `setProgress` function.
The component is conditionally rendered by the parent.

When the `ProgressBar` component is created/rendered for the first time everything works as expected, but when it is being rendered for the second time it does not update anymore although the `data` attributes change.

Excerpt from parent component:

```
<ProgressBar
  v-if="downloadInProgress"
  ref="progressBar"
  type="download"
  :onDone="onDownloadFinished"
  :onCancel="onCancel"
  style="width: 80%"
></ProgressBar>
```

`ProgressBar` component

```
<template>
  <div class="progress-bar-container">
    <div class="progress-bar-label">
      <div style="text-align: left">{{ progressText }}</div>
      <div v-if="cancelable.includes(type)" class="cancel-button">
        <button v-if="!done" class="link" @click="onCancel">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar">
      <vue-progress-bar></vue-progress-bar>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */

import { defineComponent, PropType } from "vue"

type Actions = "scan" | "download"
const actionText: Record<Actions, string> = {
  scan: "Scanning",
  download: "Downloading",
}

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    type: {
      type: String as PropType<Actions>,
      required: true,
    },
    onDone: {
      type: Function,
      required: false,
      default: () => {},
    },
    onCancel: {
      type: Function,
      required: false,
      default: () => {},
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      total: -1,
      completed: 0,
      errors: 0,
      progress: 0,
      done: false,
      cancelable: ["download"],
      $Progress: this.$Progress as any,
      progressText: "",
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setProgressText() {
      let progressText = [
        `${actionText[this.type]}...`,
        `${this.completed}/${this.total !== -1 ? this.total : "?"}`,
        `${this.errors > 0 ? `(${this.errors} Error(s))` : ""}`,
      ].join(" ")

      if (this.progress === 100) {
        progressText = "Done!"
      }

      this.progressText = progressText
    },
    setProgress(total: number, completed = 0, errors = 0) {
      this.total = total
      this.completed = completed
      this.errors = errors

      if (this.total === 0) {
        // Handle edge case (eg. empty folders)
        this.progress = 100
      } else {
        this.progress = Math.ceil((this.completed / this.total) * 100) || 5
      }

      this.$Progress.set(this.progress)

      if (this.progress === 100) {
        this.done = true
        this.onDone()
      }

      this.setProgressText()
    },
    resetProgress() {
      this.total = -1
      this.completed = 0
      this.errors = 0
      this.progress = 0
      this.done = false

      // Set a small number to make something visible
      this.$Progress.set(5)
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.resetProgress()
    this.setProgressText()
  },
})
</script>
```

Here are my logs for the lifecycle methods:
[image]

Although the `$data` object changes the displayed `progressText` remains unchanged and renders the default value of "Downloading... 0/?".
On the first render everything works fine, but on the second render it stops working/updating and the text does not get updated.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on?

Vue version: 3.0.7

EDIT:

Code from the parent component that updates the progress bar:

```
created() {
  const messageListener: browser.runtime.onMessageEvent = async (message: object) => {
    const { command } = message as Message

    if (command === "download-progress") {
      const { completed, total, errors } = message as DownloadProgressMessage
      if (this.progressBarRef) {
        this.progressBarRef.setProgress(total, completed, errors)
      }
    }
  }

  browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(messageListener)
}
```

SOLUTION:

`this.progressBarRef` was a computed property that returns `this.$refs.progressBar as any`.
Removing this computed property and always accessing `this.$refs.progressBar` directly solved the issue.
Thank you very much @Michal Levý for pointing me in this direction!

Comment: Which method is not working, you only mention one method of updating that is calling `this.$Progress.set(this.progress)`, and at the end of the question you mention that always works.. your question is not clear on what other methods are used to update.

Comment: @MatJ The only things that doesn't work is that the rendered `progressText` doesn't get updated on the second creation although the `setProgress()` function modifies this value. I have already tried adding it as a computed property or calling `$forceUpdate()` but nothing worked.

Comment: what is `progressBarRef` ?

Comment: A computed property that returns `this.$refs.progressBar as any`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

`this.progressBarRef` was a computed property that returns `this.$refs.progressBar as any`.
Removing this computed property and always accessing `this.$refs.progressBar` directly solved the issue.
Thank you very much @Michal Levý for pointing me in this direction!